# Accessing website from server on internet

Tags: ubuntu, dns, static-ip-address

how do I access my server on the internet? I would want it to have a domain of piezosystems.com, accessed on internet but not public. My router has a IP adress of 10.0.0.1, comcast, and my server 10.0.05, cannot route it to internet. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is register a domain name (or get a free one), with a dynamic DNS service (obtained from a dynamic DNS service provider) which maps that name to your ephemeral IP address (with the help of a small daemon program that you run inside your network, perhaps on your router).

Port forwarding on your router takes care of mapping requests to an internal server which is on your `10.` network. E.g. port `80` of your external address can go to port `80` of your `10.0.0.2` box, which might be a web server.

You you do not need a nice domain like `<yourname>.com`, you can get dynamic DNS free.

`piezosystems.com` appears to be taken; you would have to buy it.

Providers of Dynamic DNS can also handle your domain registration, so it's very easy "one stop shopping" so to speak.

P.S. I'm voting to move this to superuser.com.

Comment: Yes, I do have a domain name registred already, however, is it possible to register my own domain my-self?